# Two layers of glass reflection related to wave interference

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, waves, refraction, interference

A highly reflective mirror can be made for a particular wavelength at normal incidence by using two thin layers of transparent materials of indices of refraction $n1$ and $n2 (1 < n1<n2 ) $on the surface of the glass $( n>n2 )$ 
[image: Images]

Question: What should be the minimum thickness $ d2$ in the figure in terms of the incident wavelength $λ$, to maximize reflection? 

Attempt: $$\lambda\over 2 \times n_1 \times n_2 $$ However, this is wrong. I got a hint saying that the correct answer **does not containe** $n_1$.

Help appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Please note that Physics.StackExchange is *not* a homework help site. Please [see this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093)

Comment: The attempt looks like a guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The attempt looks like a guess. You should explain as much as you can about how you arrived at that answer.

A hint would be that for maximum reflection, the reflected waves should all be in phase. For that to happen, the total in-and-back distance traveled in layer 1 should be an integral number of wavelengths. Likewise, the total in-and-back distance traveled in layers 1 and 2 should be an integral number of wavelengths. Note that you will have to figure out the wavelength in each layer.

Comment: I've gotten the correct answer. Don't tell somebody else,haha